# How to make a web push notification stay open

Tags: push-notification, microsoft-edge, service-worker

I am trying to make a push notification stay open until a user interacts with it.

Have [downloaded](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop) The Blazzing Pizza example. The app is using push notification.
I added:

```
requireInteraction: true
```

to the config

**service-worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener('install', async event => {
    console.log('Installing service worker...');
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    // You can add custom logic here for controlling whether to use cached data if offline, etc.
    // The following line opts out, so requests go directly to the network as usual.
    return null;
});

self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    const payload = event.data.json();
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification('Blazing Pizza', {
            body: payload.message,
            icon: 'img/icon-512.png',
            vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
            requireInteraction: true,
            data: { url: payload.url }
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
});
```

It's not working. After 20 seconds the alert disappears.

Found a very good article about notification. Named "[Notification behavior](https://web.dev/push-notifications-notification-behaviour/)"

It only has to work on windows 10 and 11. With latest Edge and chrome

Update: I found [this site](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/) with examples on different push notifications. requireInteraction also not working there.

But it works in Chrome. Chrome is showing a close button on the notification when requireInteraction is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requireInteraction: true` should and does work on my device (Windows 10, Edge version 110.0.1587.50, same Blazing Pizza). The notification will not disappear unless I manually close it. You may have to rebuild the whole program and test again.

**UPDATE**

It looks like **the notification auto-dismissing after 25 seconds** is now **by design** and is an expected behavior in Microsoft Edge due to users' feedback. You can find more information [here](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/02/16/introducing-adaptive-notification-requests-in-microsoft-edge/). The reason why my previous test shows a different behavior seems to be that I was calling Microsoft Edge directly from Visual Studio, which works in a different way from my "normal" Microsoft Edge. Now I've tested the Blazing Pizza again in the normal one but the notification auto-dismisses this time after 25 seconds. Of course, the latest push notifications sample you've provided shows the same behavior. Edge auto-dismisses but Chrome persists.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to get the example up and running. I have removed the service worker and cleared all data using the edge dev tools. Also rebuild and cleaned my solution.
Also tried it in chrome and on another port. The notification still auto close.

Comment: Hi @MartinAndersen, I've tested your latest sample and come up with something new. Please check my updated answer.